# Create IExecutor in .net Maui for Android?

Tags: java, c#, interface, telephonymanager

I am not sure how to implement an [IExecutor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.util.concurrent.iexecutor?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13) in .Net Maui. I need this executor in order to be able to simply run a function in Android (it takes in an IExecutor as a parameter). I literally don't know how to implement all of the functions, but this object Must implement IExecutor...

```
#if ANDROID
using Java.Interop;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Util.Concurrent;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CellularSignal1
{
    public class Executor : Java.Lang.Object, IExecutor
    {
        public nint Handle => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int JniIdentityHashCode => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public JniObjectReference PeerReference => new JniObjectReference();

        public JniPeerMembers JniPeerMembers => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public JniManagedPeerStates JniManagedPeerState => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Disposed()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DisposeUnlessReferenced()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Execute(IRunnable command)
        {
            command.Run();
        }

        public void Finalized()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SetJniIdentityHashCode(int value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SetJniManagedPeerState(JniManagedPeerStates value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SetPeerReference(JniObjectReference reference)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void UnregisterFromRuntime()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

I tried just leaving as is, but was starting to get a bunch of 'not implemented' exceptions from this

Answer (score 0):

Just use your Context (Android.Content.Context) 'Executor' or 'MainExecutor'.
For example, you can get the main executor from your MainActivity like

```
public class MainActivity : ... 
{
    public IExecutor GetExecutor() { return this.MainExecutor; }
}
```

By the way, you do not have to reimplement Java.Lang.Object's properties.

Comment: Format this answer properly by highlighting jargons

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how you can get it.

**With api >= 28.0**

```
Platform.CurrentActivity.MainExecutor
```

or

```
Platform.AppContext.MainExecutor
```

but you can get a warning:

`'Context.MainExecutor' is only supported on: 'android' 28.0 and later`

**With api also < 28.0**

```
ContextCompat.GetMainExecutor(Platform.AppContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting `Java.Lang.Object` to your impementation would be enought. You don't need to implement all the stuffs of `IExecutor` except `Execute` method.

Try it again with clean file.

```cs
// it's enough
public class Executor : Java.Lang.Object, IExecutor
{
    public void Execute(IRunnable? command)
    {
        command.Run();
    }
}
```